# Missing some buttons in the titlebar of Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro

For the past few days, I'm missing buttons in the titlebar of Stack Overflow:

[image: Chrome]

The *Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™*, *Inbox* and *Achievements-Buttons* are not visible anymore. However I can still click them, they are fully functional.

It only happenes in Chrome, when I open the site in Firefox, it looks normal:

[image: firefox]

I already cleared all cookies, deleted the cache, and updated Chrome, but the buttons stay invisible.

I have no Idea why, and I'm not even sure if it's a bug? (I can't believe that Stack Overflow has bugs...)

I'm using [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) 35.0.

Comment: It's probably Google Chrome that has the bugs. Updating just means you get the latest bugs available.

Comment: Do you have AdBlock Plus or another ad-blocker installed? The image sprite for that contains the word "share" so it might be getting blocked.

Comment: Chrome 35.0.1916.114 on Win 7 is fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried hard refreshing the page?

Comment: @animuson Oh dear, Adblock blocked the buttons. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks, this was driving me crazy

Comment: Version 35.0.1916.153 m fine for me

Comment: Nice catch, @animuson.

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225831/image-of-stack-exchange-button-is-blocked-by-adblock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was, that AdBlock blocked the images. Their sprites contain the word "share".

I deactivated AdBlock, and now they're working again.

Comment: @animuson If you post your own answer, I'll delete mine, and accept yours.

Comment: Updating AdBlock's filters fixed the issue for me.