# Ad-block notice

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Sometimes I get bugs and after searching I noticed that it's because of adblock. I think that the majority of users would not be able to find this information very easily and would assume that it's a bug with the website. Although adblock notices usually are for profit purposes, I think it would be for informative purposes too, something like:

> **Attention!**
>
> It appears you're using adblock. Adblock is known to sometimes cause
>   issues with rendering certain elements. This is merely an informative
>   post for your convenience and we are not suggesting you disable
>   adblock. See meta posts #1 and #2 for a workaround. (If you suspect that there is a bug with the website and disabling adblock didn't help, please report it!) *Insert canned sentence here, "thank you for using stackexchange"*

This could go in place of advertisements that are blocked (on the sidebar). That would be the least obnoxious way of doing it. Instead of text, you could also have a rotation of community-made images (to allow others artwork to be seen). Either way, the idea is to replace the advertisements, not display a big banner.

That way you don't lose trust with users by telling them to disable adblock but they can make an informed decision on whether to disable adblock (for helping of stackexchange make money) or keep it enabled but at least make them aware it is not a site bug.

Examples:

[Empty choices in “Know someone who can answer?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280798/empty-choices-in-know-someone-who-can-answer/280799)

[Missing some buttons in the titlebar of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261023/missing-some-buttons-in-the-titlebar-of-stack-overflow/261270)

[Stack Overflow top menu bar not being rendered properly in Chrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266143/stack-overflow-top-menu-bar-not-being-rendered-properly-in-chrome/266278)

Comment: Any specific examples of adblock causing problems on SO? I only know of issues caused by other addons such as ghostery or https everywhere. Still, even if there were issues, I'm against such a notice as momst SO users employing adblock obviously have no rendering problems, and sticking a big banner in their faces warning about potential problems (which might be caused by _other_ addons) does not sound constructive. There should rather be a "what to check before reporting a rendering bug" page or faq question somewhere which should contain the hint to disable adblock and similar addons.

Comment: @l4mpi Why would stackexchange provide support for third party addons?

Comment: @l4mpi prominent example of adblock problems is the share dialog, which presents empty options, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280798/empty-choices-in-know-someone-who-can-answer

Comment: Where did I say anything about providing support for third party addons? I'm talking about a faq question on meta.SO giving people a checklist of things to do before opening a rendering bug _on meta.SO_. And @Vogel612 the share dialog is exactly my point - AFAIK ghostery blocks that too (depending on settings of course), and there are probably other addons that do so - singling out adblock doesn't seem useful. Also, there were more critical bugs caused by https everywhere, e.g. it broke mathml rendering (although that seems to be fixed now).

Comment: @l4mpi Providing an offical page or FAQ sounds like support to me.

Comment: @Grant kk. Also could have a checkbox that says "Don't show me this again" with a close button.

Comment: @user4380656 I'm talking about a question on meta.SO, probably with the "faq" tag. Similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist but more of a "meta.SO bug report checklist". That has nothing to do with support for any third party tools, but with support for people who think they just discovered a bug on SO - which is entirely in the scope of meta.SO.

Comment: The ads on SO aren't obnoxious.  You should turn off adblock and give back to the people serving you good content.  That goes for ANY website that isn't hosting obnoxious ads (background audio, autoplay vidya, etc).

Comment: @Will The existence of any ads at all are obnoxious.  I pay for my usage of SO with my time.  If that isn't sufficient, feel free to ban me or ask me to pay for access.  Otherwise, I'll use it and every other site on the internet with ads off.

Comment: And if everybody like you did the same, we wouldn't have the web we have today.  That's a fine how-do-you-do.  Good day, sir.

Comment: I'd be perfectly ok with that, I'm happy to pay for content I use.  I'm not happy to look at advertising, ever.  In fact I think we'd have a better web without it,  and I'm happy to help move us towards that.

Comment: @GabeSechan You'd rather pay for content rather than see an ad occasionally in the sidebar of a website? What about people who can't afford that luxury? A lot of sites could loose a lot of their userbase if they didn't use ads to fund themselves.

Comment: @grumpycrouton that didn't give you the right to waste my time with your ads. I will never app ad blocking, and if your ad somehow makes it around then I boycott your product. You just set your prices high enough that the payers cover the non payers. If you can't do that, your content obviously wasn't worth it in the first place

Comment: @GabeSechan So you're suggesting a paid option on content where if you don't pay you still get ads? Sort of like YouTube?

Comment: @grumpycrouton I'm saying ads are inherently bad. I will not view any. I will not use any site that tries to work around ad block. Especially as ads are a huge  virus vector. I am willing to pay for content.  If you want to show ads but work with ad block on, I accept that level of stalemate. But ads are an inherently immoral vehicle. People who but actual products pay for the ads, which go to support sites they don't use. So instead of charging the users, you're charging people who have nothing to do with the content, many of whom may also be poor and unable to afford it

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I understand your personal bias against ads, and that's fine. My question is not about you personally, but how you think websites should work in general. I don't understand your notion that "ads are an inherently immoral vehicle". Why does it matter who is paying for the ad? If someone buys something that supports an ad, I would assume they would be the kind of person to buy that product _anyways_. The point of ads is so that the user consuming the content doesn't have to pay for it, it's being paid for in another way. I agree sites shouldn't go around ad blockers though.

Comment: @grumpycrouton right. The people using content aren't paying for it. So let's say there's an ad for my favorite shirt on fashionblog.com. I don't read that content, but I pay for that shirt. So I'm paying for the add, but I never use the content. Having me, who will never use the site, pay for that content increases the cost of my item even though I have no interest in using that site. That's why ads are immoral- you're charging people who will never use the content to pay for other people to get free stuff.

Comment: As for how they should work- no ads. Paywalls are fine, limited free articles are fine, giving it away for free and charging enough to cover that it's fine. There's a variety of other models

Comment: @GabeSechan My argument to you, is that if it's your "favorite shirt" you were going to buy that product _anyways_, regardless of if it is funding an ad. I doubt any single item would really have their price effected (Beyond maybe a few cents (I assume less), as many products could pay for the same ad, these items already have a markup that pays for the ad more than likely - (sources showing otherwise would be much appreciated)). It doesn't effect the person buying the product, but it allows the average content consumer to not spend anything to view the content, I don't see how anyone loses.

Comment: @grumpycrouton doesn't matter- is inherently unfair and immoral to charge me extra to support a website I don't use on a totally unrelated item. I lose, even if it's a few pennies. Added up over everything it totals a fair amount. I'd rather pay for content I support than have it taken from me for stuff I have no interest in, or possibly even abhor (for example they could advertise on fox news, and I'd rather kill myself than give them money).  This makes an advertising system immoral.

Comment: @GabeSechan So you are saying you'd rather pay $10 to view content each month, versus a few pennies when buying items you were already going to buy? (Basing that on YouTube specifically, where they have a paid option where you don't get ads (I think this is worth it to some people because of some extra features they get that free doesn't))

Comment: @grumpycrouton I'd rather pay hundreds. 10 is a no brainer

Comment: @GabeSechan Okay, maybe you would rather pay $100, but I would venture to say _most_ people wouldn't be able to afford that. I'd take the 1c (If that, again I doubt prices change _at all_ because it supports an ad, rather the company just makes a few cents less profit), than paying for content that I could view for free. Keep in mind that $10 (Or, as you said you wouldn't mind, $100) that is a "no brainer" would be per-site that you use regularly.

Comment: @grumpycrouton so you'd rather immorally force other people to pay for your content? Well that says a lot about your character

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, but I don't think it's immoral. It goes both ways, someone buys a product that supports an ad for content that I use, I buy a product that pays for content they use, I think that is a much better system than throwing $100, $10, or even $1 at a website just to see the content. It saves everyone money, why is that such a bad thing?  Also, you keep saying something along the lines of "other people paying for your content", but what about my point about the price not changing for a product when supporting an ad? You've just ignored that point completely

Comment: @grumpycrouton I ignored it because the price does increase. No company eats it out of the goodness of their heart. I'm going to end it here because we just aren't going to agree- advertising add a way of paying for unrelated content is inherently wrong. It doesn't save everyone money, it causes parasitic losses for everyone involved except the content provider, and moral hazard for any site in journalism or information. There is no good in it. The world would be a better place without it.I should go on for hours about it, but I don't have the time

Comment: @GabeSechan What about cases of simply researching, given the implications of what you are saying? Websites you may only use a single time in your life, behind a $5 paywall. Gotta do some research? Well here is a site regarding your search, just pay $5 and you can read the content! Okay, _pays $5_, content on the page is not what I'm looking for. DAMN! Go to the next site, $5 paywall. It just doesn't work.  _price does increase_ I really don't think so, it doesn't make sense. Ads are for more than just the consumer of content, they redirect users to buy the product they are advertising.

Comment: @grumpycrouton same thing that happened before the web went ad crazy- donations and personal passion projects. Many of the best sites like Wikipedia are ad free paid by donations today. Adding ads didn't improve anything.  Or alternative revenue streams, like selling enterprise offerings that SO and github do

Comment: @GabeSechan There is a whole lot more to ads than "If ad, price goes up". Companies will usually attempt to keep their original retail prices even after advertising because 1) Competition 2) If the advertising is effective, they will sell _more_ units, thus making more money from the ad already - in the end it is up to the advertiser, maybe there should be some rules to consider for this? I could get behind that. Donations don't always work, and passion projects are often lost/abandoned due to the financial burden. I'd also like to point out I'm not really trying to argue with you, just convo.

Answer (score 4):

I've never had any bugs on any website because of adblock.  A banner telling me to turn off adblock is orders of magnitude more likely to get me to change to another site.