# Where did the "Share" link go?

Tags: support, design, hyperlinks, user-experience

I'm trying to link to another user's answer here on Meta. There used to be 2 ways to obtain a direct link to any question / answer:

1. If I recall correctly, there used to be a "share" link under every answer that would open a popup with a direct link to the answer.
2. The *"Answered <x time> ago"* text used to be a hyperlink for that answer.

Now, both of those options have been removed, and replaced by some "Follow" mechanism?

> [image]

The *"Answered <x time> ago"*  is no longer a hyperlink.

Please restore at least one of those options.

Comment: There is a share link for me right now. Is some browser extension removing it? Try safe mode, a different browser etc.

Comment: Not repro'd on Chrome 100, Windows 10, though I doubt browser/OS is related. The share link is still there, and the follow link is also there since quite a long time.

Comment: Oh, that's weird... I'll see about disabling my adblocker?

Comment: Yeap, adblocker... wtf... This can be closed as "can no longer be reproduced".

Comment: Might be related (similar cause): [Missing some buttons in the titlebar of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261270/2821954)

Comment: Nah, I've been using this adblocker (ublock) for _years_ now, @AndrewT. Either its rules have changed, or the triggering css class is new on the link.

Comment: I think it's time we coined the term "SE bug" - similarly to "Bethesda bug", one never knows whether it's a recent update that broke things or something else...

Answer (score 12):

Apparently my adblocker (uBlock on Chrome) is triggering on the `​js-share-link` class that is present on the sharelink.

I don't know if the class is new, or the adblocker rule is new, but whitelisting that  class fixes it.

Comment: A [github issue](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/issues/118667) has been filed.

Comment: I don't understand what's been up lately with ad blockers. I haven't had a single problem in years, but in the past month, I've had around 10 misfires spread across 5-6 different websites (counting SO and the SE network as one in this context, though; not that it really matters). I haven't have the share link blocked myself (yet anyway).

Comment: Could be *useful* if you could mention which Browser (+ Version) and especially which Ad-Blocker you are using... (in the Qt and/or the Answer...) // Oh...!?, `uBlock` is mentioned "somewhere" in the Comments..., but this Info belongs to the Qt and not (only) in a Comment... // + `AdGuard` is mentioned in some other Comment, so that's a bit "*confusing*"...

Comment: @chivracq: I've added the adblocker to the answer, but it's really one of the filters that's the culprit.

Comment: This issue affects any adblocker that uses the "AdGuard Social Media" list, including uBlock Origin (not a default list) and AdGuard itself (unsure if default).

Comment: `stackoverflow.com,superuser.com,serverfault.com,stackexchange.com,askubuntu.com,stackapps.com,mathoverflow.net#@#.js-share-link` is what I'm currently using to unblock on uBO.